# Haskell type signatures with varying parameters

Tags: haskell, type-signature

Project Euler #4: A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99. Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

This solution works:

```
p004largestPalindrome :: Integer
p004largestPalindrome = largest [ a * b | a <- [100..999], b <- [100..999], isPalindrome $ show(a*b) ]
    where
        isPalindrome [] = True
        isPalindrome [_] = True
        isPalindrome (x:xs) = if x == last xs then isPalindrome (init xs) else False
        largest [] = 0
        largest [x] = x
        largest (x:xs) = if x > head xs then largest (x:(tail xs)) else largest xs
```

My question is: can you assign type signatures to the functions in the `where` clause, given that the both have different arrangements of parameters ([], [x], (x:xs))?  Sticking in `isPalindrome :: (Eq a) -> [a] -> Bool` throws an error.

Edit: I am trying to insert a type signature like so:

```
p004largestPalindrome :: Integer
p004largestPalindrome = largest [ a * b | a <- [100..999], b <- [100..999], isPalindrome $ show(a*b) ]
    where
        isPalindrome :: (Eq a) -> [a] -> Bool
        isPalindrome [] = True
        isPalindrome [_] = True
        isPalindrome (x:xs) = if x == last xs then isPalindrome (init xs) else False
        largest [] = 0
        largest [x] = x
        largest (x:xs) = if x > head xs then largest (x:(tail xs)) else largest xs
```

Comment: Where exactly were you sticking that?

Comment: right before `isPalindrome [] = True`, directly beneath `where`

Comment: You have a typo. Shod be `(Eq a) =>...` (arrow should be made with equal sign)

Comment: That worked.  As did `largest :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a`

Comment: By the way, `isPalindrome` has quadratic complexity when the simpler `\x -> x == reverse x` has linear complexity. It does not really matters, since we have only short inputs, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You have a typo. [Should] be `(Eq a) =>...` (arrow should be made with equal sign) –  Michal Seweryn

Class constraints are separated from the types they constrain with `=>`.

Comment: That worked.  So does `largest :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a`